# regex: grabbing items from a list based on the word attached

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a list like:

```
x=['/category/Women-Dresses?size=0', '/brand/Free_People', '/closet/shopmyycloset', '/listing/559c0800568c896f6e019f2a/unlike', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a', None, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', None, ]
```

I want to grab the elements from the list that have the word listing in it so I want to have

```
c=[/listing/559c0800568c896f6e019f2a/unlike,/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a,/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a]
```

I thought regular expressions would be a good tool for this but I'm a little lost, this is what I tried but it doesn't work

```
import re
x=['/category/Women-Dresses?size=0', '/brand/Free_People', '/closet/shopmyycloset', '/listing/559c0800568c896f6e019f2a/unlike', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a', None, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', None, ]
c=[]
for list in x:
    if re.findall('/list',list) in list:
        c.append()
print(c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this list comprehension. It picks elements that have "listing" in them.

```
c=['/category/Women-Dresses?size=0', '/brand/Free_People', '/closet/shopmyycloset', '/listing/559c0800568c896f6e019f2a/unlike', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a', None, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', None, ]
c=[e for e in c if e and "listing" in e]
```

Comment: why do you need the and?

Comment: `e and "listing" in e` is an expression with two parts. They both need to be true for this to work. `and` does this. The first part is to make sure is e is not None. The second to make sure listing is in e. When both of them are true, it adds `e` to the list

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter`:

```
x=['/category/Women-Dresses?size=0', '/brand/Free_People', '/closet/shopmyycloset', '/listing/559c0800568c896f6e019f2a/unlike', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a', None, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', None, ]
new_x = list(filter(lambda c:"listing" in c if c else False, x))
```

Output:

```
['/listing/559c0800568c896f6e019f2a/unlike', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a']
```

Edit: using regex:

```
import re
final_results = [i for i in x if re.findall('listing', ['', i][bool(i)])]
```

Output:

```
['/listing/559c0800568c896f6e019f2a/unlike', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a', '/listing/Eyelet-drop-waist-dress-559c0800568c896f6e019f2a']
```

Comment: @ducminh True, however, if `c` is `None`, then checking if `"listing" in c` will raise `NoneType' is not iterable`. Therefore, the check for truthiness must take place.

Comment: could you have filtered out with regex ?

Comment: would you mind explaining your regex usage? what does '', do? and what does bool(i) do?

Comment: @Bob: `re.findall` will return a list if a match is found. In this case, no special regex string needs to be created, only the substring `"listing"` itself. `bool` checks for the truthiness of a value i.e `bool` will return false if passed `'', None, [], {}` etc, and true for any other values. This way, any `None` values in the list will evaluate to `False`, enabling the code to replace it with `''`. If `None` was passed to `re.findall`, a `TypeError` would be raised.